# You have one new edit. See your responses

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, revisions-list

As of recently, the notification bar also tells me when one of my posts has been edited.

It does, however, refer me to the "responses" tab of my "recent" page, instead of the "revisions" tab, where this information lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been true for months, actually, we just didn't break out the number of edits in the text.

I made it so if only edits are notifying you (rare, indeed) it will send you to `/users/recent?tab=revisions` tab instead of `/users/recent/?tab=responses`

Comment: Rare, yes. But it happened to me twice already. I guess people don't talk to me, they just correct me.