# Notify users about edit suggestion on their own posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, notifications

At the moment normal users do not get notified if someone suggests an edit on their own question or answer. I'm not even sure if they can see these suggestions if the do not have the corresponding privilege.

I think users should get notified about pending suggested edits *on their own posts* and also be able to see and accept or reject the suggestion independent from their own reputation.

Comment: Do users get notified about ordinary edits? If they do, then they should already be notified about suggested edits. If they don't, I don't see why suggested edits need a special notification.

Comment: @Robert, I *seem* to recall being notified about revisions, which should be equivalent to an 'edit,' to my answers/questions on SO. But it's been a while, so this might've changed since.

Comment: @Robert: They get notified about ACCEPTED suggested edits, but not about pending ones. The idea is that the user should be able to decide him- or herself if the edit is accepted.

Comment: I think it should work the same way that notification on non-suggested edits works now.  You can always roll back an edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @Robert: The notification is in the "revisions" in the (no longer so) new dropdown under your user name. (Before it was in the much debated envelope.)

Comment: The point (as I see it) is that if the original author is in a position to see the suggested edit, then they would be a very good person to decide whether or not to approve it.  So making it easy for them to see if there is a suggested edit on one of their contributions would be a Good Thing.

Comment: I disagree - I've run into plenty of users who have edited their question, and in doing so, made it lower quality, or removed important parts (like an edit to "Ok, thanks - question is solved now"), rather than to improve its quality. People with edit (or moderator) privileges ultimately are (generally) wiser than those who they need to edit for, and I can foresee inexperienced users becoming offended at their post being changed (say to [remove salutations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)), and deny it only for that.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: In my version, the notification would only be shown if the user had approve/improve/reject privileges anyway.  So inexperienced users wouldn't be affected.  It could be as simple as having the pending edits notification being a different colour if one of them is on one of your own posts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now that we've got a lower priority place to shove "somebody suggested an edit to your stuff" notices in the [notifications tab](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/), this will go out with the next build.

Whenever an edit is suggested to a post you own, a notification with a link to both the post and the suggested edit will be sent your way.

Random philosophical tangent, I've always felt edit notifications were a bad fit for the inbox because you typically can't *do* much with them.  Even suggested edits, which you can approve/reject, will often *already be dealt with* by the time you're notified.

Not to mention that edits on questions I asked years ago are almost certainly of no interest to me, at all.

Comment: should this be mentioned in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange]?

Comment: Wow; this is brilliant! Just got this myself. It even distinguishes between a general edit, and code being changed! Thanks!

Comment: But you can revert an edit. I have seen some questions/answers that were edited and it removed all the true meaning from the original poster.
Probably when there just a 'suggested edit' is not necessary, but it would be great to get notifications when an edit has been made (accepted). So you can go and check to see if the edit was actually useful and improves your post.

Answer (score 2):

These suggested edits will appear in the edit queue.  If you see edits in the queue, check!  One might be on a post of yours, or it might be one you can approve/improve/reject.

I'm confident that you can make decisions about more than just your own posts. It wouldn't be much more noise if the queue emphasized pending edits:

- On your own posts
- On answers to your question
- On other answers or the question for questions you've answered
- On questions and answers to questions tagged with your favorite or frequented tags

De-emphasis of questions with your ignored tags might also be a neat idea. However, let me reiterate my first paragraph: This should not be used to encourage ignoring the flag queue, or to completely hide edits that are not in one of these four categories. A quick glance at the edit queue as you scroll through should be all you need to determine whether or not an edit is on your post, on a topic you're familiar with, on a generic post, or on a topic you're unfamiliar with/don't like.

To reiterate: Any emphasis or notification should be restricted to sorting the edit queue, not to notifying or hiding suggested edits.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of suggested edits on your stuff on data.se:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1928/suggested-edits-on-my-stuff in particular there are [2 rejections on TeX](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/q/114388/suggested-edits-on-my-stuff?UserId=2975) you may want to look at.

This is quite enlightening, as a top user on TeX you dealt with 9 pages of suggested edits, yet only a fraction affected you, and a much smaller fraction were rejected.  (7 approved / 2 rejected on your stuff)

---

As it stands, normal edits do not trigger any kind of notification. The UI for revisions on your stuff is kind of obscure: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron?tab=responses&rfilter=revisions

In particular looking at your TeX example, there are many more case where people have messed with your stuff that you are oblivious to: https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/q/114393/edits-on-my-posts?UserId=2975 (62 changes)

---

Even at very high rep, the number of times that people edit your stuff is incredibly rare. Personally I think we should possibly consider adding inbox notifications when people create revisions on your stuff OR an edit is rejected.

---

Due to suggested edits being so rare, odds are you will not even be on the site when this happens. The result is what you are much more interested in. I support the idea of "edit notifications" but do not support adding notification for only a fraction of the time stuff is edited. It seems to arbitrary.

1. If the result of a suggested edit is that it is approved it is **stronger** and more likely to be correct than a normal edit (a high rep user + normal user looked at it). Why would you want to see the edits that are more likely to be correct?
2. If it is declined I agree you probably want to hear about it, in case it was too radical and you supported the radical. However the amount of times this happens is incredibly rare. I support this kind of notification, but support the listing in a stronger way. And also support a general edit notification (including declined edits) in a stronger way.

---

I support the controversial "inbox notification for edits" request.

I also support expanding: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron?tab=responses&rfilter=revisions to show rejected suggested edits (something I will do now)

---

> and also be able to see and accept or reject the suggestion independent from their own reputation.

This is already the case, you can always approve/reject edits on your stuff. Its just that you are not that likely to be around when it happens. You still see `edit(0)` on your own posts regardless of rep.

Comment: Thank you for the lock, Sam. People really took that the wrong way.

Comment: no worries, it was getting out of hand

Comment: I'm kind of confused, because being notified when someone edits your stuff used to happen: the [envelope lit up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers/36044#36044) and a [notification bar appeared](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49349/you-have-one-new-edit-see-your-responses/49377#49377). When/why did this change?

Comment: @MarkTrapp I **strongly disagree** with the fact we decided not notify people in the global inbox of edits on their stuff. Have been trying to push it, but need a meta ticket to back me up.

Comment: @waffles [Ask and ye shall receive](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/notification-when-your-answer-is-changed-by-someone-else) :)

Comment: @MarkTrapp thanks ... moved it here