# How about a notification if there's a pending edit on one of my contributions?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify users about edit suggestion on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts)

I'm not a great one for checking the "pending edit" queue, as I find myself rarely able to decide so leave it for someone more knowledgeable.  But if the edit is on one of my contributions, I'd probably be able to decide on it so would take a look.

So, as a feature request, how about a notification if there's something in the pending edit queue on a user's contributions?

Comment: It's just been pointed out to me that this is a duplication of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91556/138421 (which currently has no answer).  Feel free to close as duplicate, and feel free to answer the other one.