# What type of notifications do we have?

Tags: support, notifications, stack-exchange-button

I could not find any list so I am asking: What type of notifications do we have?

From my own notifications, I could find the following:

- A badge was awarded.
- A post I made was edited.
- A post I made was migrated to a different site.
- A bounty I started is about to expire.

I believe the notification about edited post is new since [moving the notification to the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) so assume there might be more.

Any other types? For example, what about post I made is deleted? I would expect to get notification as well, but can't test this by myself.

Comment: You received notifications about an edited post before, you just had to have not been active on the site recently I believe.

Comment: @Tim so you say that whatever notifications we used to have via the Orange Bar (R.I.P) moved as-is without adding any new types?

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't go that far...it's rather early and I haven't had coffee yet to really think about it, so it was just a side-note.

Comment: Notification for castinf vote in community moderator election!

Comment: Would this be a good candidate for [meta-tag:faq-proposed]?

Comment: @Phoenix good point, I will ask a mod here. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notifications that exist as of today (June 11th 2012):

- earned a badge

  - veteran users don't get all of these
- earned a new privilege

  - these are suppressed when creating an account
- bounty completed
- bounty expires in 3 days
- bounty expires in 24 hours
- got association bonus
- the "welcome!" message
- an election has started (nomination phase)
- an election has moved into the primaries
- voting has started in an election
- a post was migrated
- an edit was suggested on a post
- on SO only, a new reply was added to a moderator message chain

  - obviously, only moderators see these
  - everywhere else these are put in the inbox
  - even on SO, if a moderator has participated in the chain these go into their inbox
- a non-trivial<sup>*</sup> edit was made to a post

For a while before the new notifications tab was enabled the old "big orange" messages were going into it verbatim behind the scenes.  A number of those messages won't be sent anymore, but we didn't (and won't be, obviously) delete the old ones.

<sub>* a non-trivial edit is one which changes at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy). For the "technical" sites (where code highlighting is enabled) changes to code of at least 2 characters are considered non-trivial.</sub>

Comment: Ah, the election notifications are a great idea

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Couple of questions. First, what is "non trivial edit"? Peter edited this very question adding only four characters and it gave notification. Second question - is this eligible to be a faq in your opinion? (Bounty surely goes here, 6 more hours to wait though :))

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - a non-trivial edit is one which changes at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy).  For the "technical" sites (where code highlighting is enabled) changes to *code* of at least 2 characters are considered non-trivial.

Comment: What about unread chat messages? Is this new, or just overlooked?

Comment: @Kevin if an edit changes one character in title, is it considered a non trivial edit?

Answer (score 1):

- [somebody suggested an edit to your stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133550/160062)
  Whenever an edit is suggested to a post you own, a notification with a link to both the post and the suggested edit will be sent your way.

Comment: I know, it's already in my post: *A post I made was edited* :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I thought there was a difference between a post being edited (after the suggestion was reviewed,the edit being accepted and therefore final) and an edit being suggested (therefore not being final).

Comment: You were right, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple more:

- Badge was awarded.
- Post I made was edited.
- Post I made was migrated to a different site.
- Bounty I started is about to expire.
- Answer on one of my questions.
- Change on a favourite question.
- While editing a post, someone else saved an edit
- You're notified by another user in Stack Overflow for Teams of a question you might like/be able to answer.

Comment: Answer on one of my questions belong to the *inbox* tab, not notifications. Also can't see any favorite changes - got some favorites that changed, nothing is shown as notification.. can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd nope, it's in notifications (possibly *as well* but it's definitely there :)

Comment: Weird, maybe it's reputation dependent then?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd hmm could be :L  I'll grab some screenshots and ask the question :L

Comment: Notification for castinf vote in community moderator election!

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd [screenshots](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134910/are-new-answers-supposed-to-show-as-notifications-as-well-as-inbox-messages) :)