# Are new answers supposed to show as notifications as well as inbox messages?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

After Sha Dow Wiz Ard's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have/134907#comment375703_134907) on his question I'm wondering if this is intended behaviour.  When I received new answers on an Area51 discussion question and a Stack Overflow question I was alerted in both the inbox tab and the notifications tab of the Super Collider.

For other questions on other sites, this hasn't been the case:

[image: Notification of new answer]

[image: Matching inbox msg of new answer]

And also:

[image: Another notification of new answer]

[image: Another Matching inbox msg of new answer]

It only seems to have happened for those two answers, I can't tell if it's cause they're slightly older or if it's related to the site that they are on - any ideas?

Comment: Oh, those indeed used to appear as orange bar alerts when returning to the site after a while. Thought you meant you get this for every answer..