# What is shown on the Reputation tab when bounty and accepted are combined?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

This is more curiosity than anything else.

If a particular event has Accepted Answer and regular upvotes on it, then the combined score for the event will be something like `+25` with the green background from the Accept.

Similarly, if an event has a Bounty (say 200) and an upvote, it shows `+210` on a blue background.

What if you have a Bounty of 200, an Accept and an Upvote all on the same event? What is shown?

My guess is that it will show `+225` on a blue background, becaue the bounty is the most "important" event of the three, but is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, your guess is correct:

> [image: screenshot]

This is only relevant in case the reputation is displayed by post of course, when shown by time each event has its own line.

In case you wonder the above is [Kevin's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose?tab=reputation&sort=post) excellent answer to [one of my questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have).