# Add "Your post was edited" to answers in First Post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, notifications, revisions-list

A thought occurred to me recently. Currently, new users have no way of knowing if their first answer was edited. The review process allows users to clean up answers, but future posts will likely contain the same errors as the first.

It makes sense to automatically notify users of when their post has been edited to promote higher quality answers on future posts. As it stands, it seems like the first post queue's effectiveness is diminished by this.

I don't think this applies for questions, though, since people are likely to get immediate feedback on questions.

Comment: Do users no longer get notified when one of their posts is edited?

Comment: I haven't gotten any notifications. Except once, but that was for a suggested edit.

Comment: I get them. The last one I got was only back on December 29th (and no it wasn't a suggested edit). There may be other circumstances which factor into whether or not a notification goes out that I'm not aware of though.

Comment: Weird. I'm going to wait a bit and see what the consensus is here, and if everyone's getting notifications for edits, I'll delete the question.

Comment: [Proof](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xHQ7x.png) :)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I suppose the edits to my posts then are pretty minimal. Good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone will be notified of an edit to their post, [*if the edit is non-trivial*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have/135411#comment378020_135411):

> a non-trivial edit is one which changes at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy). For the "technical" sites (where code highlighting is enabled) changes to code of at least 2 characters are considered non-trivial.

Additionally, if a new user happens to be staring at their post after the edit is submitted, they'll get a little notification on the post itself that it has been changed.