# Edits to code no longer explicitly noted outside of mobile

Tags: bug, edits, notifications, top-bar

[Notifications for non-trivial edits were added a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have/135411#comment378020_135411), with a special rule for edits made to *code* within a post on sites where code is treated specially:

> a non-trivial edit is one which changes at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy). For the "technical" sites (where code highlighting is enabled) changes to code of at least 2 characters are considered non-trivial.

In addition to lowering the bar for being considered "non-trivial", edits to code were also called out explicitly in the notification itself. However, with [the relocation of these notifications to the inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign), this distinction appears to have been lost:

[image: generic "post edited" notification, even though a code block was edited]

I probably wouldn't even have noticed this, except that the old notification is still displayed on mobile:

[image: specific "code was edited" notification]

This seems like a regression; since the information is available, it would be nice to have that noted in the full-site notifications as well.