# No notification when someone with gold badge edits my question or answer

Tags: support, edits, badges, notifications

I recently asked in the [SO.pt Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4963/28595) about some edits made to my questions and answers where I wasn't notified in my inbox.

To test the "theory", I asked someone with a gold badge in a tag that I used in my question to make an edit in the question and the answer, and I did not receive a notification after editing.

The question was:

[Converter objeto em json no php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97415/28595)

and the answer was:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97571/28595

The user that edited has a gold badge in the `PHP` tag on SO.pt. Is this rule applicable for the whole SE network? That is, edits made by someone who has a gold badge in one of the tags do not notify the OP?

---

## Edit

I asked two members without a gold badge (in the question / answer tag) to do the same, and received notifications, as can be seen in this screen shot:

[image: notifications]

The revision's link:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/77689/revisions and https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/112597/revisions

Comment: This got nothing to do with gold badge, that's for sure.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I auditioned with 3 members, and only what had gold badge, I did not receive notification.

Comment: I don't see any other edits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I updated the question with print.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't get notification because nothing was actually changed.

As Kevin says in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135411/152859), the criteria for notification is:

> a non-trivial edit was made to a post

And mentions [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have/135411#comment378020_135411) what is "non-trivial edit":

> a non-trivial edit is one which changes at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy). For the "technical" sites (where code highlighting is enabled) changes to code of at least 2 characters are considered non-trivial.

Additionally, after some testing, it appears that title edits are also subject to the 10-character requirement.

Now, the edit made by the user with gold badge only added a hidden HTML comment. Nothing was actually changed, as can be seen in the diff view:

> [image]

Hence, too minor to be worth a notification.

If user without the Edit privilege (usually below 2K rep) edits, then it will always send notification, because it's a *suggested edit*, and you have to review it. So even if such user suggests that same edit (i.e. adding hidden comment) it pass as suggested edit, and you do get notification.

Comment: You're right, i see others questions that I didn't receive notification and they seem to have non-trivial edits. Thanks :)

Comment: Still unclear will I get notification if somebody edit 5 characters in the body (not a code) **and** 5 characters in the title simultaneously.

Comment: @Sonic what you think? ^