# What kind of edits of my posts by other users do not trigger an inbox notification?

Tags: support, bug, edits, notifications

I notice that not all edits of my posts trigger an inbox notification. I know that when the edit only contains a tag manipulation, then it doesn't trigger an inbox notification. But it seems there is a more complex condition (small edits?) for this. In particular, I can't find anything in my global inbox about [this edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/322224/3). Maybe the reason here is that the question was closed already?

Could somebody provide a full list of which edits do not trigger an inbox notification?

Comment: @Glorfindel according to the answer of suggested duplicate the edit that contains a title modification (my case, see the link) should be considered "substantive", but there is no notification. Should I consider to change my [support] question into [bug] then?

Comment: "The threshold varies from site to site." - that *might* be the cause but I'm not sure. I've reopened the question; please edit it to focus on this specific issue.

Comment: @Glorfindel The exact criteria are documented here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278029/no-notification-when-someone-with-gold-badge-edits-my-question-or-answer/278032#278032. Please close as dupe.

Comment: I [already closed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/322744/revisions) but wasn't satisfied with the explanation there. And it's not really clear if titles are excluded from the 10 character criterion.

Comment: @Glorfindel Did you get notified for my edit to one of your post titles?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. So it might be that the 10 character difference is right, but then this information needs to be added in the answer of the duplicate target.

Comment: @Glorfindel Edited.

Comment: Eh ... I meant into Sklivvz' answer ...

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog looks like the duplicates list should be edited to refer to the question with [your recent edit in the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278029/339911).

Comment: @älёxölüt The duplicate target is now fixed.