# (How) can I see all edits by others to all my posts?

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

I just saw a subtle but damaging edit suggested on one of my relatively popular answers on Stack Overflow, and thankfully it was rejected. As I understand it: for some reviewers it wouldn't have been possible to arrive at an approve/reject decision before spending possibly several minutes reading the question and understanding the answer. Given this, obviously, some of them chose to (incorrectly) "approve" the edit after what I assume was a quick glance. Why? Who knows. Reviewing edit suggestions is probably associated with a badge and thus there is incentive for reviewers to be quick rather than thorough with their reviews.

This scares me. I don't mind edits to my posts and wouldn't contest one even if it appeared (to me) to not bring any/much additional value to my post, but I certainly don't want edits to them that simply fly under the radar and make them wrong.

Is there a way I can see a list of all edits by others to all posts I ever made? I'm not requesting a notification on every edit, but a way to see these edits by clicking an appropriate link in the web UI.

Comment: Non trivial edit will cause inbox notification, so you can see them all in your [global inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) on the network profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Nice! How and where is "non trivial" defined?

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135411/152859).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find edits that others made to your posts on your profile page. It's under "responses/revisions".

On your profile page, go to the "Activity" tab.
From there, select "responses" and under that heading, "revisions".

Or go there directly, filling in this template of the URL:

```
http://<stack exchange site>/users/<user-id>/?tab=responses&sort=revision
```

I can see a "deleted 2 characters in body" edit in this history on my own page, so this overview does include minor edits.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not aware of any functionality in the Stack Exchange UI to get such a list. But fortunately, this is quite easy to get via a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/586650/my-posts-which-were-last-edited-by-someone-else).

This is how the list looks for me, on Stack Overflow:

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], LastEditDate, Body
  FROM posts
  WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
    AND LastEditorUserId != OwnerUserId
  ORDER BY LastEditDate DESC
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.