# Should the recent feature changes post include a note about pending suggested edit notifications?

Tags: support

Today, on Ask Different, I saw a notification about a pending edit for one of my posts.

[image: screenshot]

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) doesn't seem to contain any note about that feature, nor did I find any post about that either.

Should [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) be updated to include that feature too?

Comment: There might be a reason the "recent feature changes" post wasn't updated yet.  They're waiting for the feature to stabilize, or rchern is on vacation, something like that. "Recent feature changes" isn't updated in real-time.

Comment: Here's the post about it: [Notify users about edit suggestions on their own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts).  Looks like it was implemented about a month ago =)

Comment: I feel like that feature changes list is already missing quite a lot...