# Is there a way to get notified when a question I answered gets modified?

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify us when the question has been edited after posting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer)

I keep noticing that some of my answers become rather off topic or even irrelevant due to the question it addresses is edited by its owner (or - by all means - someone else).

It seems to be left for each individual's common sense how to actually modify any given question, hence it's not always reflected that certain key points might have gone through extensive change or even been removed, which in turn leads to my very problem: my answer isn't necessarily interesting or even accurate any more.

**Is there a way, any way, to get notified when a question I've answered is modified (so I can make corresponding changes if necessary to my answer)?**

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts

Comment: I'm not sure your link addresses my question (but then again: I'm not God's brightest child). I would like to get notified when *other peoples questions* are edited, but only if I have answered to that question.

Comment: @Ramy I think you need to read his question one more time ;). He doesn't want to know when someone edits his questions, but rather when he has answered a question and the OP edits the question.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard: You're perfectly correct in your "possible duplicate...". The referred question is exacly what I was asking for. Can I highlight the (according to me) utter importance of the topic, more than by upvoting the other question?

Comment: @dbm only way is by starting a bounty, but from my experience after throwing [thousands of points](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on feature requests I favored I fear that there's really not much we can actually do.

Answer (score 0):

I just favorite the question in such situations.

Comment: Once upon a time we had a cool envelope that turned red when there was change in favourites.. however since it's demise there's no notification anywhere, one have to visit the favorites tab to look for changes.

Comment: In what situations? Every time you submit an answer? Some people have thousands of answers.

Comment: There's a lot of collateral there. Comments, new answers and edits to answers on a favorite all notify you.

Comment: @MartinSmith Not every time, just when I think I'll want to keep tabs on a question, so to speak. Sometimes something will raise an old favorite up to the surface and I'll un-favorite it because now I've been reminded I don't need to follow it anymore. It's far from a perfect system, just the way I do things.