# Suggested edit showing up for own post, but not enough reputation to do anything

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I received a notification on SO about a suggested edit on my own post with a suggestion that I should review it. I was surprised, since I have 1,4k rep there and can't review edits. However, when I clicked on the notification, I [was shown the edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebLUB.png) and a "Next" button. When I clicked the button, I [was informed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uANqU.png) that I don't have enough reputation... which I already knew.

Is this a bug, or a feature? I saw [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133550/215093) and think that it could be related to the new feature not being totally thought out, but then again, it's not that new a feature (if I judge by the date of the post). In any case, it's confusing, since you can't do anything with the edit. My question is should this happen at all?

Comment: No, the suggestion has already been rejected. You clicked `Next` but the next suggestion was not something you had the reputation for to review because it was not a suggestion on your own post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always allowed to review edits made to your own posts (but I understand that they also are enqueued, so they may be accepted or rejected in case that you don't take action). The 2k requirement is for reviewing edits made to other people's posts.

Comment: This answer is actually clearer about why my reputation doesn't matter in the case. Accpeted.

Answer (score 2):

That suggested edit had already been rejected by 3 other people. Therefore it does not need to be reviewed anymore.

So basically, you were late. There's nothing you needed to do. And it has nothing to do with your reputation.

Comment: But if I wasn't late, then I take it, that I would have been able to do something (approve/reject)?

Comment: Yes, if you got to it before enough people had reviewed it, you would have been able to approve/reject it yourself.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was curious, since it hadn't happened before.