# Could I get a notification in my inbox, if someone edits a post of mine?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, global-inbox

> **Duplicate:**
> [Notify us when one of our posts is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited) - this is really a duplicate.
> **Not a duplicate:**
> [Optional notification on an edit to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer) - This is about something else, but still useful.

Not often, but still sometimes, someone edits my posts. I know I can see a [list of those on the "revisions" tab of the "responses" view in my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600500/paulo-ebermann?tab=responses#rpage_1-rfilter_revisions), but then I would have to look there regularly. Could I get a notification of those edits in my global inbox?

(I just checked, there is no such mention in [my global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/3687974d-c7d4-45c3-8eae-759a11847f5d?tab=inbox) (It would be on page 9/10 now, for the last edit of one of my posts).)

Much more often actually I'm editing posts (questions/answers) of other people, and I think it would be fair if they would get a notification about these, even if I don't post an explicit comment.

The message could be something like:

> edit on  **Why do java arrays have no indexOf method?**
> Added: return NOT_FOUND;

I.e. first the question title, then the edit comment. The link could either go to the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6931749/revisions) or the [question/answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931461/why-do-java-arrays-have-no-indexof-method/6931749#6931749).

The inbox could also include suggested edits on my posts by people who don't yet have enough reputation, so I could approve/reject them myself, without needed intervention of other edit-approvers. (They would still be visible on the global queue, of course.)

Comment: There is another question named [You have one new edit. See your responses][5], but this seems to be from before the global inbox, and about a top-of-page notification bar. Just mentioning this so this question does not get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Here's the link: [You have one new edit. See your responses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49349).

Comment: See also [Optional notification on an edit to an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97740).

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks. (I just cut-n-pasted this from the question (and not reread.)