# Notification when your answer is changed by someone else?

Tags: feature-request, bug, edits, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify users about edit suggestion on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts)

It seems that you do not receive notification when one of your answers is edited by someone else. Is this by design or has it never been recommended before?

The reason I ask for this is because of [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/why-is-naming-a-tables-primary-key-column-id-considered-bad-practice/114734#114734). Most of the time people edit my questions/answers to fix grammar mistakes, but in this case someone edited my answer to "fix" a query that was *supposed* to be broken. Mildly annoying.

It was an easy enough to fix, but it seems that getting an alert would have made it much easier to recognize that a goon had edited my answer without fully reading it.

Am I the only one who thinks this would be useful?

Comment: The fact that this question was edited is now proof to me that the world is at peace :)

Comment: Heh, just making sure it's tagged appropriately. :)

Answer (score 6):

You do receive a notification, but it's somewhat buried: if you go to the [responses tab on your profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/5039/stargazer712?tab=responses), you'll see the revision.

Before the Stack Exchange drop-down inbox notification system, there was an envelope next to your name that indicated many of the same things the inbox notifies you about now. In that system, [it did notify you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers/36044#36044) when a revision was done. It also used to be the case that [a notification bar would appear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49349/you-have-one-new-edit-see-your-responses/49377#49377) alerting you to the revision.

These features seem to have been lost, so it seems like a bug to me.

**Edit:** As recently as October 6th, Sam "waffles" Saffron (an SE, Inc. developer) mentioned [there is no notification when someone edits your stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts/108508#108508) although he does support such a feature. Not really sure what happened, so I guess this is part [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), part [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and part [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I definitely think that you should get a notification when your post changes in some way, whether that's an edit by someone else, a comment (this already happens), it goes community wiki, or so on. Just like a "hey, something has happened to your post, you might want to go check it out and see what's up".