# How would I find which of my posts have been edited by someone other than myself?

Tags: support, edits, data-explorer

Can you point me to the api and query syntax so I can determine which of my posts have been edited on one or more Stack Exchange sites by users other than me?

I am looking for a query to retrieve the results which I may wish to add further filtering.

[Notify users about edit suggestion on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts?lq=1) and [Notification when your answer is changed by someone else?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109765/notification-when-your-answer-is-changed-by-someone-else?lq=1) are about notifying users when a suggested edit has been posted whereas I am looking for a list of my posts that have been edited by users other than myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notify users about edit suggestion on their own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109765/notification-when-your-answer-is-changed-by-someone-else/109766#109766 , just go to your profile, click "responses", then click "revisions"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with a [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/293219/posts-that-were-edited-by-other-users):

```sql
Select ID As [Post Link], LastEditorUserId As [User Link], LastEditDate
From posts
Where OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
    And LastEditorUserId <> ##UserId##
Order By LastEditDate Desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an API or a query syntax. Just go to your profile and click Responses. If you have a lot of responses, you can filter to just Revisions. You should see something like this:

[image: revisions]

The question title is a link or you can click the arrow next to it and see the changes that were made.

Comment: Thank you Kate but this does not answer my question.  I don't want to do visual screen scraping. I would like a set of results I can query, manipulate with further filters and then export to excel.